# In a Xamarin App, how do write a method that starts a new activity?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-activity, xamarin.android

I want to be able to switch pages within my Xamarin App easily.

I've looked at clear examples on how to do this in java for Android Studios and I know Xamarin should be extremely similar, but I'd like to know the exact syntax in C# and an easy way do it in Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

You use `StartActivity`:

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(YourNewActivity));
StartActivity(intent);
```

Xamarin has a quick start that covers this:

re: [Hello, Android Multiscreen: Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/hello-android-multiscreen/hello-android-multiscreen-quickstart?pivots=windows)